# Running Swift code in while loop but times out

Tags: swift

I have following code that is supposed to do two things:
1) Fire blasters when temp is under 100 and blasters are not overheated.
2) Wait out until the temp is cooled down to zero.

I am not too sure why the codes below time out. I am a real beginner with Swift (I have an intermediate background in R.)

```
var shields = 5
var blastersOverheating = false
var blasterFireCount = 0
var temp = 0

while shields > 0 {

    temp = temp + 1
    blasterFireCount = blasterFireCount + 1

    if temp == 100{
        blastersOverheating = true
    }

    if blastersOverheating{

        print("Sleeping to cool down to 0")
        sleep(10)
        temp = 0
        blasterFireCount = 0
        blastersOverheating = false
        continue
    }

    print(temp)

}
```

Comment: What do you think that `while shields > 0 { ... }` does, in particular if `shields` is nowhere modified?

Comment: Yes. I don't mind if it does not terminate because that's not the problem. I forgot to add something above, I added "print(temp)" so it can print the temperature, but it does not.

Comment: Then what is the problem? Where does the code "time out"? Where do you print the variable? Did you *debug* your program?

Comment: What do you mean by timeout? Do you want your blaster to restart blasting after it is cooled down or do you want it to stop?

Comment: If you run it here: https://iswift.org/playground, you will know what I mean

Comment: Well yes, it will timeout in an online playground as the program never terminates. It's unclear exactly what result you're expecting.

Comment: I am not sure why it is not printing 'temp' at the bottom of the code.

Comment: Does not produce any output in Xcode

Comment: @JamesRyu Outputs fine for me in Xcode. If you're in a playground, you need to look in the debug area at the console. Although really you should always test Swift code in a full project (playgrounds are really buggy and unreliable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this code on a free online platform (like  iswift.org/playground), your program will time out because it would run forever otherwise.

To counter this problem limit your loop so it only does, for example, 1000 cycles.

View the example online: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59123b184ee0cd258050b2cd

```
var coolingDown = false
var blasterFireCount = 0
var temp = 0

for _ in 0..<1000 {

    if coolingDown {
        temp -= 1
        print("cooling down \(temp)")

        if temp == 0 { coolingDown = false }
    } else {
        temp += 1
        blasterFireCount += 1

        print("fire \(blasterFireCount)")

        if temp == 100 { coolingDown = true }
    }

}
```